# HTTP Get with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i want to change the url: 'server/php' static value to the $ObjektId, can someone help me ? thx

```html
<script>
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'server/php/'
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
</script>

<?php
$ObjektId = $_GET["immo_id"];
?>
```

Comment: You cannot get a variable that you have not defined yet. Define it first, then use PHP in your JavaScript. Depending on your needs you may want to use AJAX instead, keeping your PHP on a separate page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set value to `$ObjecktId` first. Here is how you can do it:

```
<script>

<?php
$ObjektId = $_GET["immo_id"];
?>

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: $ObjektId
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
</script>
```

However `$ObjecktId` is misleading name for a variable that contains URL, i suggest you use something like `$ObjectURL`.

Answer (score 0):

put it in hidden field then get in the jquery using

so your code will be

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: $('#hiddenFieldId').val,
}).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
    data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code would help you achieve what you want.  But I am not sure why you are doing this. Assigning the url dynamically makes sense if it changes everytime.  Since you are saying that it is static value this is same as hardcoding the url.

```
<script>

    var ObjektId = <?php echo $_GET["immo_id"]?>;


    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: ObjektId
    }).on('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
        data.formData = data.context.find(':input').serializeArray();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Adding some explanation with this would be helpful.